# Hexa to Decimal in snowflake

Tags: hex

> ```
> I need a query to convert hexa value to decimal value. below is the query
>
> For 0xE7 the decimal value is 231.
>
> How to convert hexadecimal value to decimal value in snowflake.
> Below is the query I am trying to execute
> ```
>
> > select
> > hexa_decode_string(concat(substr('0x00E7000101000000'::varchar,1,2), substr(replace('0x00E7000101000000'::varchar,'0x'),3,2)));

Comment: Check the native SQL answer at https://stackoverflow.com/q/71919021/132438 (this question didn't have the Snowflake tag, hence it was ignored at the time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to write JS UDF and below is one:

```
create or replace function hex_to_int (input string) 
returns double language JAVASCRIPT 
as 
'if (INPUT !== null)
{
op = parseInt(INPUT, 16);
}
return op';
      
select hex_to_int('0xE7');
```

Comment: Check the native SQL answer at https://stackoverflow.com/q/71919021/132438 (this question didn't have the Snowflake tag, hence it was ignored at the time)